# How can I load an image without use html?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, image, web

How can I load a image without add html element?

I'm making a game with typescript. Right now, I'm stopped by loading image.

We can use HTML to load image, and then use 'document.getElementBy()' but It will let code be too unclean:

```
<img src = "..."> 
<!-- What if a need hundred of image here? -->
```

And I don't want to switch to html tab every time, after I typed in , I don't need html anymore, and leftover are all done by typescript.

Are there any way to load image in javascript / typescript only?

```
LoadImage("...") // and gives you a image
```

ps: I don't want css too because it's even worse.

Comment: Yes, there is such way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Comment: Load image and do what with it? If you want to display it in an HTML document, then what is wrong with an `<img>`? Are you asking how to generate HTML using JavaScript? Try an introductory tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: @Quentin Because I need to make a game. Just like what I did before in java, create class, and let image object be property of class. When I need that, 'new' a object and draw them on the screen, objects are saved in arrays and lists, like that

Comment: And how do you plan to render the image? Are you generating image elements? Rendering them on a `<canvas>` Or something else?

Comment: @Quentin yes, draw it at canvas in document